# How to make AUI validation apply only when a check box is selected?

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I have fields in an aui form that I only want to be required when a corresponding checkbox is selected, otherwise they're not required. I'll enable these input fields using `<aui:script>` once the check box is enabled and only then aui validation should work.

I have tried with hiding the `<aui:validator>` depending condition in script.

How do I enable the validation only if my check box is selected in aui?

```
<aui:form action="" method="post">
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="employeeId" id="employeeId"></aui:input>

<div id="employeeDetails">
    <aui:input type="text" name="name" id="employeeId2">
        <%
            if (true) { //default i kept true how to check this condition on check box basic
        %>
        <aui:validator name="required"'  />
        <%
            }
        %>
    </aui:input>
    <aui:input type="text" name="email" id="employeeId3">
        <%
            if (true) {
        %>
        <aui:validator name="required" />
        <%
            }
        %>

    </aui:input>
</div>
<aui:button-row>
    <aui:button type="submit" />
</aui:button-row>
</aui:form>

<aui:script>
AUI().use('event', 'node', function(A) {
   A.one('#employeeDetails').hide(); // to hide div by default

   var buttonObject = A.all('input[type=checkbox]');
   buttonObject.on('click', function(event) {
     if (A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>employeeId").attr('checked')) { 
        A.one('#employeeDetails').show(); //for checked condition
     } else {
        A.one('#employeeDetails').hide(); // for non checked condition
     } 
   });
});
</aui:script>
```

Reference images:

Before enabling the check box

[[image: Before enabling the check box]]

Check box enabled:

[[image: check box enabled]]

Comment: Next time you're asking a question: [Decide for one place to ask or clearly link your crossposts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample `if(true)` bothers me - it's evaluated server side on the JSP and won't have *any* effect, since `true` is always `true`.

However, your question is well documented within [Liferay's documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/forms-and-validation): Look for "Conditionally Requiring A Field"

> Sometimes you’ll want to validate a field based on the value of
>   another field. You can do this by checking for that condition in a
>   JavaScript function within the required validator’s body.
>
> Below is an example configuration:
>
> ```
> <aui:input label="My Checkbox" name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
>
> <aui:input label="My Text Input" name="myTextInput" type="text">
>   <aui:validator name="required">
>     function() {
>       return AUI.$('#<portlet:namespace />myCheckbox').prop('checked');
>     }
>   </aui:validator>
> </aui:input>
> ```

Comment: Dear @olaf thanks for the reply. 
The document solution work, but misses to remove the asterisk from the field. How may this could be achieved?

Kind regards